# app signing key google play getting error : can not recover key using pepk.jar

Tags: android

[image]I'm getting the error shown in screenshot when using the command

```
 java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=mynews.jks --alias="My News" --output=mynews.ppk --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I entered the wrong password. When you build an app from Android Studio and sign it you have to enter your master password first and then two others. You have to enter those two passwords, not the master password :)

Comment: This is regarding pepk.jar not regarding release build, my master password and all credentials working

Comment: That's what I am talking about as well, when I tried to export the encryption key and so on with pepk.jar I entered the wrong password and it threw this error to me as well :)